# Uniform convergence of series argument

Tags: analysis

Hey guys so I have the following series.

$\sum x^2/(1 + n^2x^2)$ and asked of it will uniformly converge or not on R.

I am mean I see it that it will diverge but I can't see a formal argument that I can write.

Comment: It certainly does not diverge. It converges at every point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series converges for all values of $x$, since $$1+x^2\nu^2\geqslant x^2\nu^2\implies \sum_{\nu \geqslant 1}\frac{x^2}{1+x^2\nu^2}\leqslant\sum_{\nu\geqslant 1}\nu^{-2}<\infty$$ and the series is of nonnegative terms. This in particular proves uniform convergence by Weierstrass' majorant criterion.